# Automatically reload localStorage data from API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am grabbing data from a JSON API, multiplying it with the users input, then storing that data in `localStorage`. I would like for the data to be updated, and re-multiplied every time the page reloads. I have not been able to find a solution. Here is a link to my current set-up

https://jsfiddle.net/GxPro/vffv7hhv/1/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <h2>Price of Bitcoin</h2>        
        <img src="img/BTC.png" />  
        <p id="lastPrice"></p>
        <h3>Your Holdings</h3>    
        <p id="userBTC"></p>
    </div>
    <br />

    <input type="number" id="userInput" />
    <button id = calculate>Enter the ammount of BTC you own</button>

    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function (data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].symbol == "BTC") {
      var price = JSON.parse(data[i].price_usd);
      $("#lastPrice").html("$" + price); //last Price
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function calculate() {
    var text = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var userAmmount = text * price;
    localStorage.btc = "$" + userAmmount.toFixed(2) + " (" + text + " BTC)"; 
    $("#userBTC").html(localStorage.btc); 
  }
  $("#userBTC").html(localStorage.btc);
});
```

Comment: If what you mean is the value of Your Holdings display the latest value after you refresh the site, it seems work, isn't it?

Comment: @vicnoob The price of BTC changes rapidly; when the price changes the number of holdings does not adjust to the new price of BTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you should store only the amount of btc, not the whole string. Then when you call the API, check if the localStorage has that property, use it to calculate the result. I updated the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vffv7hhv/18/

```
  $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      if (data[i].symbol == "BTC") {
        var price = JSON.parse(data[i].price_usd);
        $("#lastPrice").html("$" + price); //last Price
        if (localStorage.btc) {
          $("#userBTC").html(calHolding(localStorage.btc, price));
        }
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function calculate() {
      var text = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      localStorage.btc = text;
      $("#userBTC").html(calHolding(text, price));
    }

    function calHolding(amount, price) {
      return "$" + (amount * price).toFixed(2) + " (" + amount + " BTC)";
    }
  });
```

Comment: You're a hero! It works but I do not fully understand the logic behind it? Are you just saying that if localStorage.btc is called upon then run the function calHolding? Edit: very new to JS. Thanks for the help

Comment: @GxPro I checked if the btc variable is stored before in the localStorage, if it is not null or undefined, then print to the text to the html part. Which part you do not understand? I can help

Answer (score 0):

Considering your line of code:

`localStorage.btc = "$" + userAmmount.toFixed(2) + " (" + text + " BTC)";`

I presume you want to store data in `localStorage.btc` variable, and you want this to be multiplied every time whenever a user clicks the button. What is happening as per your code is that, the data stored in your `localStorage.btc` is getting overridden every time a user clicks the button.

So, instead of doing it this way,
I'd say you do the following:

- Use one more variable in localStorage as a temporary data saver
- Then keep multiplying `localStorage.btc` variable with your newly received data
- Then store `localStorage.btc` to the temporary data saver again

In this way, you will be able to keep multiplying the necessary values.